# Converting sqlite to sqlite format inside Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: sqlite, titanium, appcelerator

Here is my issue. I am using Titanium Appcelerator to build an app that accesses my database and other various things. I have two separate files. One being an et.sql file in readable format and the other et.sql file with a top line of SQLite format 3�Ä��@ and the rest being ASCII or some text in an unreadable format.

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('et.sqlite','et');
var db = Ti.Database.open('et');
```

This produces an sql file that gets installed inside a folder that the app will use in the future.

When using this et.sql file with the header of SQLite format 3Ä@ it is accepting it inside Titanium and the app builds with my code, the other file that is formatted it doesn't accept. It seems like it needs to be in sqlite format.

I am using SQLite Manager for Firefox to update my sqlite file with new tables, etc that in turn gets installed in Titanium that produces an sql file. Problem here is I can't seem to reproduce a sql file that is in sqlite format. The previous developer didn't leave any notes on how to do this and I've struggled to produce this file in a format that works. I've looked into using sqlite3 command line, but I've had no luck. How do I get titanium or sqlite for that matter to dump this file in sqlite format so that it can be used inside Titanium?

I am fairly new to sqlite so if I'm overseeing anything just point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) command-line tool to convert between text files containing SQL statements and SQLite database files:

```sh
sqlite3 newfile.sqlite < oldfile.sql
sqlite3 oldfile.sqlite .dump > newfile.sql
```